# problem with sObject as parameter

Tags: class, sobject, parameters

I get the below error when I try saving CLASS 1 below. The second class that is the problem is also below. I obviously don't understand objects or apex well, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [Decimal].getSmallQtyPenalty(Decimal, SOBJECT:Mfg_Run_Charges_Rate__c)
>   at line 27 column 42

CLASS 1:

```
public class MOChargeRate{

   public static decimal getMOChargeR(boolean noWin,
                                       boolean MOWinDie,
                                       boolean punchWin,
                                       boolean dblWin,
                                       boolean furnBlank,
                                       boolean furnPrePrint,
                                       decimal wrkPerMQty,
                                       decimal wrkQty,
                                       List<Mfg_Run_Charges_Rate__c> mfgRCR){

      decimal MOCharge = 0.0;
      decimal punchChgAmt = 0.0;
      decimal winPenalty = 1;
      decimal punchUpchg = 0;
      decimal furnPenalty = 1;
      decimal smallQtyPenalty = 1;

      for (Mfg_Run_Charges_Rate__c MO : mfgRCR){
         if (wrkQty < 50000){
             if (MO.Pricing_Code__c == 'MO'){
               if (MOWinDie){ 
                  if (furnBlank){
                     if (MO.Window__c == 'Special Window' &2& (MO.Furnished__c == 'Blank' || MO.Furnished__c == 'Both')){
                        smallQtyPenalty =smallQtyPenalty.getSmallQtyPenalty(wrkQty, MO );
                        winPenalty = MO.Window_Penalty__c;
                        break;
                 }
               }
            }
         }
       }
      }
      return MOCharge;
 )
```

---

SECOND CLASS:

```
public class smallQtyPenalty{

   public static decimal getSmallQtyPenalty(decimal qty,
                                            Mfg_Run_Charges_Rate__c m){

      decimal smQtyPnlty;
      if (qty >= m.Small_Qty_1_Min__c && qty <= m.Small_Qty_1_Max__c){
         smQtyPnlty = m.Small_Qty_1_Penalty__c;
      } else if (qty >= m.Small_Qty_2_Min__c && qty <= m.Small_Qty_2_Max__c){
         smQtyPnlty = m.Small_Qty_2_Penalty__c;
      } else if (qty >= m.Small_Qty_3_Min__c && qty <= m.Small_Qty_3_Max__c){
         smQtyPnlty = m.Small_Qty_3_Penalty__c;
      } else if (qty >= m.Small_Qty_4_Min__c && qty <= m.Small_Qty_4_Max__c){
         smQtyPnlty = m.Small_Qty_4_Penalty__c;
      }
      return smQtyPnlty;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your local variable:

```
decimal smallQtyPenalty = 1;
```

is hiding the class name `smallQtyPenalty`. (That is the compiler has discarded its idea that smallQtyPenalty is a class name in favour of thinking that it is a Decimal object and a Decimal object does not have a method called getSmallQtyPenalty on it.)

Simplest fix is to change the name of the smallQtyPenalty local variable.

This [Type Resolution and System Namespace for Types](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_namespace_type_resolution.htm) documentation lists the reference lookup order. (Thanks sfdcfox.)

Comment: I'd recommend linking the scope resolution documentation.

Comment: @sfdcfox If you know of a good Apex link or generic link please add to the answer

Comment: That would be this: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_namespace_type_resolution.htm. I think it'd be useful for future travelers to find this document.

Comment: @sfdcfox Added.